# Cannot upload image to wordpress (nginx+varnish+apache)

Tags: wordpress, apache, file-upload, nginx, varnish

I'm running two servers.

- One is a gateway running nginx for dispatching requests for different domains to different servers.
- The other one is the the server for my WordPress installation.

I'm using Varnish in front of Apache to do caching stuffs (only caching, no load balancing). I've turned off `KeepAlive` and set `Timeout` to 20 seconds for Apache.

Now I'm uploading an image of size 160KB and it fails, while my server configuration allows a maximum size of 20MB. After I submit the upload form in WordPress, I can see from the status line of my browser that the file is uploaded several times (mostly 2 or 3). When I use the asynch uploading plugin of WordPress, I can also see the progress bar growing from 0% to 100% and over and over again, until it fails.

When it fails, it stucks at the path `/wp-admin/media-upload.php?inline=&upload-page-form=` and Chrome says "Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset." I've tried Firefox, exactly the same.

I cannot see anything relevant in the error logs of Varnish and Apache. However, I do see mutiple lines of the following log in the access log of nginx:

```
220.255.1.18 - - [01/Jan/2013:12:16:36 +0800] "POST /wp-admin/media-upload.php?inline=&upload-page-form= HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "http://MY-DOMAIN/wp-admin/media-new.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.101 Safari/537.11"
220.255.1.29 - - [01/Jan/2013:12:16:41 +0800] "POST /wp-admin/media-upload.php?inline=&upload-page-form= HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "http://MY-DOMAIN/wp-admin/media-new.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.101 Safari/537.11"
220.255.1.23 - - [01/Jan/2013:12:16:51 +0800] "POST /wp-admin/media-upload.php?inline=&upload-page-form= HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "http://MY-DOMAIN/wp-admin/media-new.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.101 Safari/537.11"
220.255.1.26 - - [01/Jan/2013:12:17:03 +0800] "POST /wp-admin/media-upload.php?inline=&upload-page-form= HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "http://MY-DOMAIN/wp-admin/media-new.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.101 Safari/537.11"
```

So what's the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: How about php error log?

Comment: @KostiaShiian There's no separate PHP log files. PHP logs should be in Apache logs. Also I had this issue long time ago when it was a Rails app so maybe PHP is not the cause.

Comment: I mean error_log directive in php.ini file. But this is disabled by default. You can also check error_reporting directive. Also it is possible that code which handle uploading doesn't check all. As alternative you can use sniffer like ethereal.

Comment: I had the same problem too, but changing the network and it just solved the problem.